# Can't archive react-native project in XCode for staging configuration with Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

- react-native: 0.50.3
- xcode: 9.1 (9B55)

I have 3 configuration:

1. Default
2. Stage
3. Production

In 1 and 3 Product > Archive is working fine. When I try to archive Stage, I got an error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-carrier_mobile_app
```

This error appears after adding Pods in my project. Podfile looks like

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'carrier_mobile_app' do
  # Pods for carrier_mobile_app
  pod 'RSKImageCropper'
  pod 'QBImagePickerController'
end
```

I think I should configure Pods for Stage configuration correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Referring to this here: https://medium.com/@guyeldar/setting-up-multiple-build-configurations-for-your-xcode-project-c237265e8324

Theoretically adding $(BUILD_DIR)/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME) to your Header, Framework, and Library search paths in your targets will work. However, it only worked one time for me, then I accidentally changed something, and it hasn't been working since. Worth a shot, though.